# Estou precisando fazer uma comparação utilizando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso resolver um exercício aparentemente simples para um curso de JavaScript, mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Preciso pegar os dados de um formulário onde adiciono o nome, sobrenome e idade de uma pessoa, criar uma lista das pessoas que vou adicionando e após isso, fazer uma comparação de idades para mostrar ao usuário quem é a pessoa mais velha.

Eu já consegui fazer o formulário e adicionar as pessoas criando a lista..
só esta faltando fazer a comparação de idades e mostrar quem é a pessoa mais velha para o usuario.

Nesse link deixei um video com a minha duvida mais explicita para vocês entenderem um pouco melhor, o que estou pretendendo resolver. https://youtu.be/KP7rTY710NE

```js
function adicionarPessoa() {
    let nome = document.querySelector("#nome")
    let sobreNome = document.querySelector("#sobreNome")
    let idade = document.querySelector("#idade")
    let lista = document.querySelector("#lista")
    let registro = document.querySelector("#registro")
    registro.textContent = "Registros de:"

    let nomeCompleto = `${nome.value} ${sobreNome.value}: ${idade.value}`
    nome.value = ""
    sobreNome.value = ""
    idade.value = ""

    let pessoaRegistrada = document.createElement("li")
    pessoaRegistrada.textContent = nomeCompleto

    lista.appendChild(pessoaRegistrada)
}

document.querySelector("#botao").addEventListener("click", adicionarPessoa)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>teste</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <label>
        Nome:
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" />
      </label>

      <label>
        Sobrenome:
        <input id="sobreNome" type="text" name="SobreNome" />
      </label>

      <label>
        Idade:
        <input id="idade" type="number" name="idade" />
      </label>

      <button id="botao" type="button">Adicionar</button>
    </form>

    <p id="registro"></p>

    <ul id="lista"></ul>

    <p id="comparacao"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: percorre a lista pegando os atributo de idade e quando tiver percorrendo vai ter um if que vai armazenar a idade em uma variavel somente quando a atual idade for maior que a que ja esta armazenada

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção é criar uma variável que mantenha a idade da pessoa mais velha (você pode utilizar um [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos) se tiver que armazenar mais informações sobre a pessoa).

Assim, iniciamos o valor como `0` e, se a pessoa que inserimos tiver idade **maior** que o número que temos armazenado, atualizamos o valor e a mensagem que informa a pessoa mais velha.

Algo assim:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const oldestPanel = document.getElementById('oldest-panel');

// Variável que utilizaremos para manter a idade da pessoa mais velha:
let oldest = 0;

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const name = form.elements.name.value;
  const age = parseInt(form.elements.age.value, 10);
  
  // Insira na lista ao invés de dar um `console.log`...
  console.log('Registrado: %s, que tem %d anos.', name, age);

  // Se a idade do indivíduo atual for maior do que a da pessoa mais velha (anterior):
  if (age > oldest) {
    oldest = age;
    oldestPanel.textContent = `A pessoa mais velha (${name}) tem ${age} anos.`;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="name" type="text" />
  <input name="age" type="number" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<div id="oldest-panel"></div>
```

Desse modo você evita ter que percorrer uma lista completa cada vez que uma pessoa nova for adicionada. Fazemos uma simples verificação a cada novo "registro".

Não modifiquei o seu código (fiz um novo) para evitar dar-lhe a resposta completa. Isso é apenas uma ideia que funciona para o seu caso.